# Installing iPython on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, ipython, requirements.txt

To install iPython on my local machine, I need to do:

```
$ pip uninstall ipython 
$ pip install ipython[all]
```

How can I specify this [all] requirement in requirements.txt for heroku server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could install on your local machine, possibly in a python [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv/) and then use:

```
pip freeze
```

to generate an initial requirements.txt